# What are the best Architecture/design pattern/Best Practices for modular/component based development : part 2

Tags: grails, multi-tenant, modularity

### It is second part of my Original Question:[Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492639/what-are-the-best-architecture-design-pattern-best-practices-for-modular-compone)

I have one Multi-Tenant Grails-based application(just migrated to Grails 2.1). Now I want to add many new features in my application, but my basic requirement is that all new modules should be configurable for each Tenant and the code base should be modular and loosely coupled with other features/components.

In the short term, I want to convert my application into a module-based application which should be able to used as a plug-and-play base and also be able to configure it on a per-Tenant basis. In General, all new components/features are web-based.

So My Question is :
**How to manage code base**: I like to know the which approach I should follow for code base separation. 
a. Create a new plugin for each new module.
b. Create a new module in Spring and use same in my application.
c. Use OSGi framework for new module.
d. Create a new web application for each new module and configure application with CAS.
e. What are the best practices should be followed in this scenario.
 
I like to know the ideal solution/suggestion in terms of design and architecture or Grails plugin . Also let me know If there is any issue with my requirement……

Answer (score 1):

There are several design patterns you can use.
For the base architecture the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) might come in handy.

For a good overview google "GOF design patterns". GOF stands for Gang of Four, the writers of the book. More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).

Design patterns offer you solutions for ever returning problems. Being familiar with them is good.

Comment: The gang of four isn't going to help with the physical design of his architecture.